# Can't install VSIX Visual Studio extensions on arm64?

Tags: visual-studio, arm, vsix, windows-11, vsixmanifest

I can't get any themes to install in Visual Studio 2022 on my arm64 Windows machine. The VSIX always error out.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running VS 2022 in Win11 arm64, you've probably noticed that you may have a native Visual Studio, but you can't get any extensions to install-not even themes!

Well, I figured out why. It's because even theme VSIX packages are tied to a specific set of target architectures, and it will refuse to install on anything else even if it would work just fine.

Anyway, here's how you install a theme:

1. Get yourself 7-zip
2. Open the VSIX file by right-clicking and choosing `Open Inside`
3. Locate `extension.vsixmanifest`, and right-click that and choose `Edit`
4. Find this tag: `<ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>` and change `amd64` to `arm64`
5. Close the editor, and say yes when 7-zip asks you if you want to update the file.

The theme will now install with no problems.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

in order to remove the signature from VSIX you need to remove folders:

- _rel
- package

from the archive.

I successfully have installed ODT4VS to Visual Studio 2022 Pro ARM64

Comment: Were you experiencing issues related to the code signing of the package? I haven't seen that before. What was the issue, and why did removing those folders fix it?

Comment: Deleting these folders allowed me run the installer, it said it was successful. However when I actually tried to open an EDMX file within VS 2022, I get an error "Could not load file or assembly MIcrosoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Sdk.Diagrams.GraphObject". 

Did you have to manually install anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I am also running into this issue. After modifying the extension.vsixmanifest file as you described the installer does run, but I am seeing other errors related to OS versions.

This is the Oracle Developer Tools for VS extension. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...

This is the last half of the install log:

```
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM - The extension with ID 'Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0' is not installed to Visual Studio Professional 2022.
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM - Extension Details...
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM -     Identifier         : Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM -     Name               : Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2022
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM -     Author             : Oracle Corporation
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM -     Version            : 21.11.0.0
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM -     Description        : Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2022 is a free VS addin that makes it easy to browse and modify Oracle schema objects and data, edit and debug PL/SQL, generate SQL deployment scripts, perform schema comparisons, tune SQL and .NET app performance, and much more.
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM -     Locale             : en-US
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM -     MoreInfoURL        : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index-097110.html
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM -     InstalledByMSI     : False
12/11/2023 8:04:33 PM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -     SignatureState     : InvalidSignature
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -     SignedBy           : Oracle America, Inc.
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -     Certificate Info   : 
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         [Subject]       : CN="Oracle America, Inc.", O="Oracle America, Inc.", L=Redwood City, S=California, C=US
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         [Issuer]        : CN=DigiCert Trusted G4 Code Signing RSA4096 SHA384 2021 CA1, O="DigiCert, Inc.", C=US
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         [Serial Number] : 060E2F8F9E1B8BE518D5FE2B69CFCCB1
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         [Not Before]    : 3/8/2023 7:00:00 PM
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         [Not After]     : 3/11/2025 6:59:59 PM
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         [Thumbprint]    : CD7BE0F00F2A5EE102C3037E098AF3F457D3B1AB
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -     Supported Products : 
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -             Version : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -             ProductArchitecture : arm64
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -             Version : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -             ProductArchitecture : arm64
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -             Version : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -             ProductArchitecture : arm64
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -     References         : 
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -     Prerequisites      : 
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         Name         : Visual Studio core editor
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -         Version      : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM - Signature Details...
12/11/2023 8:04:34 PM -     Extension is signed with an invalid signature.
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM - BEGIN: Processing extension pack
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM - END: Processing extension pack
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM - Initializing Install...
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM - Searching for applicable products...
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Professional 2022
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM - The extension with ID 'Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0' is not installed to Visual Studio Professional 2022.
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM - Extension Details...
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM -     Identifier         : Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM -     Name               : Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2022
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM -     Author             : Oracle Corporation
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM -     Version            : 21.11.0.0
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM -     Description        : Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2022 is a free VS addin that makes it easy to browse and modify Oracle schema objects and data, edit and debug PL/SQL, generate SQL deployment scripts, perform schema comparisons, tune SQL and .NET app performance, and much more.
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM -     Locale             : en-US
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM -     MoreInfoURL        : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index-097110.html
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM -     InstalledByMSI     : False
12/11/2023 8:04:37 PM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     SignatureState     : InvalidSignature
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     SignedBy           : Oracle America, Inc.
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     Certificate Info   : 
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         [Subject]       : CN="Oracle America, Inc.", O="Oracle America, Inc.", L=Redwood City, S=California, C=US
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         [Issuer]        : CN=DigiCert Trusted G4 Code Signing RSA4096 SHA384 2021 CA1, O="DigiCert, Inc.", C=US
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         [Serial Number] : 060E2F8F9E1B8BE518D5FE2B69CFCCB1
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         [Not Before]    : 3/8/2023 7:00:00 PM
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         [Not After]     : 3/11/2025 6:59:59 PM
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         [Thumbprint]    : CD7BE0F00F2A5EE102C3037E098AF3F457D3B1AB
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     Supported Products : 
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -             Version : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -             ProductArchitecture : arm64
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -             Version : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -             ProductArchitecture : arm64
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -             Version : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -             ProductArchitecture : arm64
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     References         : 
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     Prerequisites      : 
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         Name         : Visual Studio core editor
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -         Version      : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM - Signature Details...
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     Extension is signed with an invalid signature.
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM - Initializing Install...
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM - Searching for applicable products...
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Professional 2022
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM - The extension with ID 'Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0' is not installed to Visual Studio Professional 2022.
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM - Extension Details...
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     Identifier         : Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     Name               : Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2022
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     Author             : Oracle Corporation
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     Version            : 21.11.0.0
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     Description        : Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2022 is a free VS addin that makes it easy to browse and modify Oracle schema objects and data, edit and debug PL/SQL, generate SQL deployment scripts, perform schema comparisons, tune SQL and .NET app performance, and much more.
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     Locale             : en-US
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     MoreInfoURL        : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index-097110.html
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     InstalledByMSI     : False
12/11/2023 8:04:38 PM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -     SignatureState     : InvalidSignature
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -     SignedBy           : Oracle America, Inc.
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -     Certificate Info   : 
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         [Subject]       : CN="Oracle America, Inc.", O="Oracle America, Inc.", L=Redwood City, S=California, C=US
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         [Issuer]        : CN=DigiCert Trusted G4 Code Signing RSA4096 SHA384 2021 CA1, O="DigiCert, Inc.", C=US
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         [Serial Number] : 060E2F8F9E1B8BE518D5FE2B69CFCCB1
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         [Not Before]    : 3/8/2023 7:00:00 PM
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         [Not After]     : 3/11/2025 6:59:59 PM
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         [Thumbprint]    : CD7BE0F00F2A5EE102C3037E098AF3F457D3B1AB
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -     Supported Products : 
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -             Version : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -             ProductArchitecture : arm64
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -             Version : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -             ProductArchitecture : arm64
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -             Version : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -             ProductArchitecture : arm64
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -     References         : 
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -     Prerequisites      : 
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         Name         : Visual Studio core editor
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -         Version      : [17.0,18.0)
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM - Signature Details...
12/11/2023 8:04:39 PM -     Extension is signed with an invalid signature.
12/11/2023 8:04:43 PM - Blocking processes:
12/11/2023 8:04:43 PM - InstallProgressPage ChangeType: 'SingleInstall' operationCount: '2' Text: 'Installing Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2022...'
12/11/2023 8:04:43 PM - The following target products have been selected...
12/11/2023 8:04:43 PM -     Visual Studio Professional 2022
12/11/2023 8:04:43 PM - Beginning to install extension to Visual Studio Professional 2022...
12/11/2023 8:04:43 PM - Instantiate download manager silently: False
12/11/2023 8:04:43 PM - Failed to create scheduled task: UpdateConfiguration_S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415
12/11/2023 8:04:43 PM - Failed to create the update configuration task for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool: (9,79):UserId:S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415
12/11/2023 8:04:47 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Windows.UniversalCRT.Msu.8: The current OS Version '10.0.22631.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.2,6.3)'.
12/11/2023 8:04:47 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Windows.UniversalCRT.Msu.81: The current OS Version '10.0.22631.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.3,6.4)'.
12/11/2023 8:04:47 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Net.4.8.FullRedist.20H2: The current OS Version '10.0.22631.0' is not in the supported version range '[10.0.19042,10.0.22000]'.
12/11/2023 8:04:47 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Net.4.8.FullRedist: The current OS Version '10.0.22631.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1.1,10.0.17763]'.
12/11/2023 8:04:47 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Remote.DbgHelp.Win8: The current OS Version '10.0.22631.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.3]'.
12/11/2023 8:04:47 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Remote.DbgHelp.Win8: The current OS Version '10.0.22631.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.3]'.
12/11/2023 8:04:47 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Windows.UniversalCRT.Msu.7: The current OS Version '10.0.22631.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
12/11/2023 8:04:47 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.VisualStudio.NuGet.PowershellBindingRedirect: The current OS Version '10.0.22631.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
12/11/2023 8:04:47 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.KB2882822.Win7: The current OS Version '10.0.22631.0' is not in the supported version range '[6.1,6.2)'.
12/11/2023 8:04:47 PM - Skipping non-applicable package Microsoft.Net.4.8.1.FullRedist: The current OS Version '10.0.22631.0' is not in the supported version range '[10.0.19042,10.0.22000]'.
12/11/2023 8:04:50 PM - Package signature verification returned InvalidSignature for path: Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0.vsix
12/11/2023 8:04:50 PM - Cache failed. Retrying download of 'Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0,version=21.11.0.0'.
12/11/2023 8:04:50 PM - Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
12/11/2023 8:04:50 PM - Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
12/11/2023 8:04:50 PM - Activity threw exception System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
12/11/2023 8:04:50 PM - Skipping cache of package 'Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0,version=21.11.0.0' since installing or downloading it failed
12/11/2023 8:04:50 PM - Skipping cache of package 'Component.Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0,version=21.11.0.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
12/11/2023 8:05:01 PM - Install Error : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package 'Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0' failed to download
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.<Install>b__14_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.Install()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallModule.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extensionToInstall, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallModule.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallModule.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstallModule.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package 'Oracle.VsDevTools.17.0' failed to download
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.<Install>b__14_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like that particular VSIX is digitally signed, so if you change the contents, it invalidates the signature. It’s being rejected on that basis. Perhaps you could search something like visual studio extension ignore invalid signature. Good luck!

Comment: Looks like you just got your answer from @Bartek